# Is it still possible to buy a new computer with ISA slots?

Tags: isa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ISA bus on newer computers](https://superuser.com/questions/82009/isa-bus-on-newer-computers)

Is it still possible to buy a new computer with ISA slots?

Or are adapters available or some sort of solution to allow ISA cards to exist in a modern PC?

Comment: I just bought a new Motherboard... It didn't even have PCI slots. Good luck with this quest.

Comment: Similar question: [ISA bus on newer computers](http://superuser.com/questions/82009/isa-bus-on-newer-computers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are still a few manufactures out there that make new motherboards with ISA slots. But due to the low demand (I presume), they're not cheap.

- [ADEK MB-P4BWA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HLOQH6) at `USD 349,-`
- [IEI / IMBA-9454ISA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MN2Y50) at `USD 315,-`

Adapters exist, but they're not cheap either.

- [RTD PC/104-Plus PCI to ISA Bridge Module with Advanced Digital I/O](http://www.rtd.com/pc104/UM/bridge/BRG17088-M.htm) at `USD 245,-`.

Comment: And even these are a few generations old - they're c2d based.

Comment: The adapter seems like a good choice. The price is not so important. The device I need connected is more expensive than the adapter. Ta.

Comment: Adek has updated it's product line to include a Q77 based LGA1155 board.  While Haswell and LGA1150 will soon leave it a generation behind as well this refresh keep procurement of replacement systems relatively simple for the next few years.  Since TPM modules (for boot time encryption key storage) interface over an ISA equivalent bus, the chipset level support needed to make an ISA capable board is unlikely to go away anytime soon. http://www.adek.com/ATX-motherboards.html

Comment: I'm no expert in economics, but doesn't low demand mean lower prices?

Answer (score 3):

There are some companies, such as [ADEK](http://www.adek.com/ATX-motherboards.html), which still make motherboards with ISA slots. However, those are only for some older CPUs (Core 2), and won't be cheap due to their rarity.

Also, there are [adapters](http://www.arstech.com/item-USB-2-0-to-ISA-card-ROHS-usb2isar.html) to allow ISA cards to be used over USB, but then you might need to write your own device drivers.

Comment: The adapters don't come with drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many.  I have several that I use.  Check out e-Bay   You may not be able to get one with the latest and greatest CPU's, but if you are using ISA, this may not be important.  I'm not and still running Windows 2000 with no ill effects.